# Migrate postgresql to MariaDB

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, migration, utf-8

I try to migrate mysql Zabbix database from Postgresql to MariaDB using MySQL Workbench migration Wizard

I have compiled psqlODBC and enable it

When I setup the source database in the wizard the test goes wrong with the following error:

> SystemError: DataError("('220', '[220] E\x00R\x00R\x00O\x00R\x00:\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00v\x00a\x00l\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00b\x00y\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00q\x00u\x00e\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00e\x00n\x00c\x00o\x00d\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00"\x00U\x00T\x00F\x008\x00"\x00: (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.connect

Postgresql logs shows the following error on each test:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe0 0x81 0xb3

Here is database definition:

> zabbix    | zabbix   | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |

Is there another way to migrate data or a solution to understand which is the query that produce this error?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't think ODBC was that good with character sets (I could be wrong). [this answer](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/migrating-from-postgresql-to-mariadb/) might be one way using MariaDB connect engine to [JDBC connect to Postgres](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-jdbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/#using-a-federated-server). And then the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693166/exporting-database-from-oracle-and-importing-into-mariadb/74695359#74695359) for each table.

Comment: The query that produces the error is generally in the log just after the error itself, preceded by `STATEMENT:`